# when erc 4337 on arbitrum assert error AA95 out of gas

Tags: ethereum

when erc 4337 on arbitrum assert error AA95 out of gas
my hash:

https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x1825ab9d21320c7ee94ae9f81b52b13e2bb98e185d11b907e7fe881e498d3b35
I increase callGaslimit but no use

is there any reason or doc for i can know what happend ?

when i cancel less code and less calldata like this hash:

https://arbiscan.io/tx/0xe04329949db43ff127c852ebdb260dd2045941543559769bf7d0f8a23bf652fc

make very confused